# Difference In Difference method : How to find control group

Tags: difference-in-difference

I am trying out DID as part of coming up with a model to estimate the effect. Below is the scenario:
I have around 2000 items for test group(Item count may increase or decrease). Challenge is to find control group which follows similar trend as test, since an eCommerce site hosts millions of items. 
Is there a better way to identify control group ? Like any score or any other approach?

I have tried a simple methodology where I tried finding delta (this week vs last week and so on...), delta difference(wk1 vs wk2 delta , wk3 vs wk4,... delta) for test and other items to find similar trend. 
for example sales delta for test wk1 = -9% wk2 = 2% and wk3 = 6%. Any item which matches similar delta, I consider them as part of control group.

But problem here is control list changes every time/every week and count sometime less than test.

Thanks again for the guidance.

Thanks in advance, 
Nivas

Comment: This will be hard for the following reason. Imagine the treatment is a sale on flip flops. You try to find something that has a similar trend, which turns out to be sandals and sun hats. But when you drop the price on flip flops during the test, that changes the demand for sandals and hats since these two are substitutes and complements, respectively. In some sense, the best control group is likely to be the one that is affected by the general equilibrium effects (aka SUTVA violations) from the price change, biasing the DiD estimate. Your treatment is altering the untreated control outcome.

Comment: Thanks @DimitriyV.Masterov for your comment. So what if I consider other categories like toys or electronics, category unrelated to flip flops for control group.